# Laravelcollective/html not working in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I've tried to use the `Laravelcollective/html` on laravel 5.5 by loading the v5.4 in my `composer.json` file but that didn't work. This is the code in the `composer.json` file:

```
"laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0",
```

and loading it into my app configuration file `app.php`: inside the providers array

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

But after i used the blade code to create the form it didn't work, here's the blade code.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store']) !!}

{{Form::label('title','Title:')}}

{{Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control') )}}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 5):

Install `laravelcollective/html` via Terminal/CMD:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html:^5.5.0
```

In `app/config/app.php`, add the following:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
],

'aliases' => [
    // ...,
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
],
```

And in your blade file:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store']) !!}
{!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
{!! Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: `composer install` will look at the composer.lock file, and `composer update` will update all packages, not just the laravelcollective/html package.

Comment: Hi sisve, thanks for that. Whats wrong with installing all packages? Is it only done in dev env or what?

Comment: That means that all the referenced packages will be updated. You'll get a new version of laravel/framework and all the 20 packages that laravel/framework references. This means you will suddenly get the latest Carbon version that is severely broken just because you wanted to generate some html forms. Point is; it updates packages you aren't expecting to be updated. https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/863

Comment: oh stuff :O how can I install only 1 package at a time, then I'll update my answer? I can google it, but I'm sure the next person might also learn from it. :)

Comment: `composer require laravelcollective/html:^5.4.0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command

```
composer require --update-with-all-dependencies "laravelcollective/html 5.6.*"... since you are using laravel 5.5 the command to use will be 
composer require "laravelcollective/html 5.5.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add the following to your alias array:

```
'aliases' => [
// ...
  'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
  'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
// ...
```

],

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is old style.

```
{{Form::label('title','Title:')}}
```

It needs to be

```
{!! Form::label('title','Title:') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in laravel 5.5 too.
Step 1: Install from Command: `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.5"`

Step 2: After install you have to add providers and aliases in config/app.php file, so let' follow bellow file how to add.

Step 2.1:

```
<?php

'providers' => [

    // ...

    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

    // ...

  ],

'aliases' => [

    // ...

      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,

      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

    // ...

  ],
```

Step 3: After added above providers, you have to check on your project.

Step 4: Done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it Simple use this one:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```