# FormFacade class doesn't load Bootstrap classes in Laravel 5.5

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to load Bootstrap classes with FormFacade in a view but doesn't work.

I tried this steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46392838/3444714

But the Form class is generating fields without the effects of Bootstrap.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('testField', 'Test:') }}
    {{ Form::text('testField', null, ['class' => 'form­-control']) }}
    <input type="text" id="testField" name="testField" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Check my attachment, same code, but the field generated by FormFacade is wrong.

[image: Error with FormFacade]

Thank you.

Comment: Have u used `php artisan make:auth` command for authentication???

Comment: Yes, I think the issue is related to the rendering, but I'm not sure.